# How to specify the number of cores for task manager/task slot in flink

Tags: apache-flink

Give the following yarn-session command:

yarn-session.sh -d -n 12 -tm 4096 -qu QueueX -s 4 -jm 2048

We specify the memory for the task manager as 4096, and also we specify the number of slots for each task manager as 4. and  throughly 1/4 of task manager's memory is allocated to each task slot.

Then, what about the CPU cores?

Can we specify the number of cores for each task manager?(By default, each yarn container will only has one core). And further, can we specify the number of cores for each task slot?

If we don't specify the number of cores, how many cores each task manager / task slot will use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the number of vcores is set to the number of slots per TaskManager, if set, or to 1, otherwise. The number of slots per TaskManager is specified by `taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots` parameter in `flink/conf/flink-conf.yaml`. If you want to allocate a number of vcores for each TaskManager, different from slots number, you can additionally provide the `yarn.containers.vcores` setting in `flink/conf/flink-conf.yaml` - the number of virtual cores (vcores) per YARN container.

Comment: Thanks @mikalai-lushchytski. If I set  `yarn.containers.vcores=1` in `flink/conf/flink-conf.yaml`, and I have set the num of task spot per TM as 3, then from YARN's point view, I have requested only 1 vcore, but actually, TM will use 3 vcores, kind of cheating YARN, I would ask how to work out this situation.

Comment: @Tom actually, I used this vise versa: specified the less slots per TM, but more `yarn.containers.vcores` - this way YARN allocated containers with more vcores then slots per it and used additional vcores for some aside computations. In your case, if you acquire just 1 vcore, TM will use only 1 vcore, just 3 different threads.

Could you please clarify your use case - what are you going to achieve ? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @mikalai-lushchytski.  eg, I use the command `$FLINK_HOME/bin/yarn-session.sh -d -n 12 -tm 1024 -s 3` to  startup a flink cluster. Each task manager will have 3 slots. If I have yarn.containers.vcores=3, it is OK. But if I have specified -s 4 or -s 5, then each TM will still request 3 vcores from YARN. But TM will has as many threads as the number of slots, which means TM actually use more cores than it requests.  I would ask whether there is command option to specify the number of vcores for the TM when I kick off a flink application(session mode or job mode)

Comment: If TM request 1 vcore and run 3 threads, it would mean that TM will use 3 cpu core to run the threads simultaneously,because TM process is  limited with the memory size,but not limited to use the cpu core,

Comment: According to https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/config.html#full-taskmanageroptions, `taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots` just defines the number of slots, multiple flink threads can share the same core so if you specify less `yarn.containers.vcores`, then the allocated container will contain exaxctly this amount of cores and slots will share them (as doc states, it can be half of cpu cores: "this value is typically proportional to the number of physical CPU cores that the TaskManager's machine has (e.g., equal to the number of cores, or half the number of cores)"

Comment: thanks @mikalai-lushchytski. I think we should not add the `yarn.containers.vcores` in the yaml config file,then the container vcores for the TM will be equal to number of slots for the TM